# Google Hangouts and XMPP support

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

Had a question about Google's support for XMPP.  I want to build a mobile chat client on top of google chat that can interoperate with google chat run from within Gmail or any other service.  Would this application be possible to build since has announced that it will drop support for XMPP for their new Hangouts product?  Are there any alternative techniques to allow interoperable chat with Google accounts?

Answer (score 10):

Actually, they removed server to server (s2s) federation.
Third-party software works as client to server (c2s) is still enabled, even if we don't know for how long.

As [Google says](https://developers.google.com/talk/)

> Note: We announced a new communications product, Hangouts, in May 2013. Hangouts will > replace Google Talk and does not support XMPP. The information in this Developer's > Guide pertains only to Google Talk.

More info:

- http://windowspbx.blogspot.de/2013/05/hangouts-wont-hangout-with-other.html
- http://www.theverge.com/2013/5/15/4318830/inside-hangouts-googles-big-fix-for-its-messaging-mess

Answer (score 3):

What's annoying is that users who have switched to Hangouts still show up as online if you have added them as a contact; your messages to them just go into a black hole.

From what I can tell, non-hangouts-enabled users can still connect and chat with non-Google users just fine using XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Hangouts does not support XMPP as of today's release. This was a difficult decision taken by Google :(

[via The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2013/5/15/4318830/inside-hangouts-googles-big-fix-for-its-messaging-mess)

Comment: So what you're saying is that it would be impossible for me as a developer to build an ios app with google chat embedded?  It will not allow me to communicate with Google chat servers or use google contacts for this purpose?

Comment: This is incorrect. They removed support for server federation, but not client-to-server XMPP.

Comment: I can tell that my Jenkins sends me Hangouts messages. See [Jenkins Jabber](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jabber+Plugin) plugin as I've updated the Wiki.

Comment: @Wernight what is your configuration to make it work?